# Como pegar os mesmos resultados que tenho no Google Search comum, através da Api Google Search?

Tags: php, api, google-api

**Quando pesquiso Chris Brown através da api obtenho esses resultados:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Porém na pesquisa do Google pelo navegador os resultados são diferentes:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Suposições:**

- Através da busca no site, mesmo eu não estando logado, a busca ocorre baseada em alguma informação adicional extraída do navegador. Ip e língua, por exemplo...
- Pensando nessa forma imaginei que talvez pudessem existir parâmetros que possibilitassem que eu utilize a api da mesma forma que o navegador.

**Alguém tem alguma idéia mais profunda das diferenças da busca de cada um e como eu posso torna-los iguais ou semelhantes?**

Código:

```
<?php
    $query = urlencode('Chris Brown');
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=".$query;
    $body = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($body);


    for($x=0; $x < count($json->responseData->results); $x++){
        echo "<b>Resultado ".($x+1)."</b>";
        echo "<br>URL: ";
        echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->url;
        echo "<br>VisibleURL: ";
        echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->visibleUrl;
        echo "<br>Título: ";
        echo $json->responseData->results[$x]->title;
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: No início da pergunta já posso perceber que tem algo a ver com localização. Veja se na API tem alguma configuração de localização/país/idioma/etc..

Comment: Se possível coloque o link da documentação da API na pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem como pois eu estava utilizando uma API antiga a Google Web Seach API, que está obsoleta.

Vou trocar pela atual, a Google Custom Search API para tentar obter os resultados que preciso.

Answer (score -1):

Eu Tenho Um Codígo JS Que Faz Uma Request e Retorna O Valor Obtido e Por Ele Usar o Seu Navegador Para Enviar a Request Ele Deve Ter Os Mesmos Resultados Da Google Search Comum Codigo(requer jquery):

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function searchGoogle(Query) {
// Seta A Variavel Final
final = {}
// Faz a Request Com o Cors-Anywhere Para Burlar A CORS-POLICY
shweb = $.ajax({url: 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + Query, async: false})
// Seta A Variavel Que Contem o HTML Da Pagina
shhtm = stringToHTML(shweb.responseText)
// Seta A Variavel Shres Com a Class 'LC20lb DKV0Md'
shres = shhtm.getElementsByClassName('LC20lb DKV0Md')
// Faz Um Loop Entre Os Links
for (i = 0; i < shres.length - 1; i++) {
// Seta O Final
final[i] = {href: shres[i].parentElement.href, title: shres[i].innerText, desc: shres[i].parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.children.item(1).innerText}
}
// Retorna O Valor Final
return final;
}
```